# 1994 Toyota Celica - Possibly getting too much fuel and causing a flooding condition

Tags: toyota, starting, celica

This car was running fine and then one day it wouldn't start. I let it set for a couple days and then it started right up. I drove it around for about 12 miles and then parked it. When I went to start it I ran into the same problem.

I have replaced the fuel regulator an that didn't fix anything.

***Does anyone have any ideas regarding what the issue might be or a way to troubleshoot the problem?***

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Thanks for the question.  Interested in seeing what the answer to your issue is.  Cheers!

Comment: When you tried to start the vehicle, did the starter turn the motor over?  Any additional information on what happens when you try and start it will be helpful.  There are a lot of things that can cause an engine to not start, explaining what happens can reduce the possibilities considerably.  You can edit your question and add any additional facts to it if you think of of some things.

Comment: I'm going to throw out there I'm wondering if the issue is an injector (or maybe two) which is stuck open. You could check this by putting a pressure gauge on the fuel rail and checking to see if the pressure drops over time. If the problem is you cannot start it *right after you shut it off*, this is not the issue. It takes a bit (15-20 minutes) for it to get to the point where it would act like it is flooded.

Comment: Can you confirm if it gives you trouble starting only when the engine is hot or warm?

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of flooding on start in this era Toyota is a failure of the coolant temperature sensor. When it fails the ECM thinks the engine is -40 deg F. The ECM therefore adds much extra fuel to help with this false arctic weather start. The warmer the actual temperature the harder it is to get it started.

To test for this check the voltage on the sensor of the light green wire. About .5 volts is normal for a fully warm engine. Failed will read over 4 volts.